# AngularJS migration from v1.1.5 to v1.5.8 Argument 'Login.Controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to migrate an angularJS from version 1.1.5 to the latest 1.5.8 but I am getting this error:

> angular.js:13920 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Login.Controller' is not a function, got undefined
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=Login.Controller&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

js

```
var app = {};
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])

//Login Controller
Login = {
/**
 * Initializes the login page.
 */
controller: function ($scope, $location, User) {
    Login.initializeScopeVariables($scope);
    Login.createScopeFunctions($scope, $location, User);
},
initializeScopeVariables: function ($scope) {
    $scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername = null;
},
createScopeFunctions: function ($scope, $location, User) {
    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.$root.filters = {};
        Login.resetForm($scope);
    }
    $scope.submit = function () {
        Login.submitForm($scope, $location, User);
    }
    $scope.validate = function () {
        if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
            $('#submit-btn').linkbutton('enable');
        } else {
            $('#submit-btn').linkbutton('disable');
        }
    }
    $scope.$root.submitPasswordReminder = function () {
        if ($scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername) {
            mask(true);
            User.sendPasswordReminder($scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername).success(
                function (data) {
                    mask(false);
                    if (data.status == M2M.Response.ERROR) {
                        error(data.statusMessage);
                    } else {
                        info(Locale.get('passwordReminderSent'));
                        $scope.clearPasswordReminderForm();
                    }
                }
            ).error(errorCallback);
        }
    }

    $scope.$root.clearPasswordReminderForm = function () {
        $('#forgot-password-window').window('close');
        $scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername = null;
    }

    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (13 == event.keyCode) {
            $scope.submit();
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        if (27 == event.keyCode) {
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    })
},

/**
 * Resets login form
 *
 * @param $scope
 */
resetForm: function ($scope) {
    $scope.username = '';
    $scope.password = '';
    $('input').removeClass('validatebox-invalid');
},
/**
 * Submits login form
 *
 * @param $scope
 * @param $location
 * @param User
 */
submitForm: function ($scope, $location, User) {
    if (!($scope.username && $scope.password)) {
        return;
    }
    mask(true);
    User.authenticate($scope.username, $scope.password).success(
        function (data) {
            if (data.status == M2M.Response.ERROR) {
                mask(false);
                error(data.statusMessage);
            } else {
                location.href = 'main.html';
            }
        }
    ).error(errorCallback);
}
```

}

html

```
        <div class="login-area" ng-controller="Login.controller" style="width: 1300px; margin: auto">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <div class="login-panel" ng-form name="loginForm" align="center">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><fmt:message key="username"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="easyui-validatebox w140" type="text" name="username"
                                   data-options="required:true"
                                   ng-model="username"
                                   ng-change="validate()"
                                   required/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><fmt:message key="password"/></td>
                        <td><input class="easyui-validatebox w140" type="password" name="password"
                                   data-options="required:true"
                                   ng-model="password"
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   ng-change="validate()"
                                   required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <a id="submit-btn" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-ok',disabled: true"
                               ng-click="submit()"><fmt:message key="submit"/></a>
                            <a id="reset-btn" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="iconCls:'icon-undo'"
                               ng-click="reset()"><fmt:message key="reset"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="clr tac small">
                    <a href="#" id="forgot-passwd" onclick="$('#forgot-password-window').window('open')"><fmt:message
                            key="login.forgotPassword"/></a>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="clr tac">
                    <fmt:message key="login.disclaimer"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I can not figure out why this is happening in angular's latest version.

Do I need to make changes in the code?

Comment: Where is the part where you do `app.controller`

Comment: Dudette! where is your login controller?? you know it should look something like `app.controller("loginCtrl", ..,function(){});` ??

Comment: Yes I know, Neither have I seen something like this before, but that was the code and was working just fine
`Login = {
controller: function ($scope, $location, User) { ... }`

Comment: can't have done, angular needs to have knowledge of it

Comment: @CallumLinington I have not written this thing, this is an old Application that I am trying to upgrade it. 
And it is working perfectly in angular v1.1.5

Comment: Angular has significantly changed between 1.1.x and 1.5.x. Compare the [1.1.4 documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngController) and the [latest documenation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) for `ng-controller`

Answer (score 1):

this is how you define a controller. please refer to this [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Angular needs to know which..err..component is a service, which a factory, which a controller etc. so you register it with your module like `yourApp.controller`.

in the example above, `GreetingController` will be the name of the controller. so in your case, it'll become `loginController`. you define all the functionality in the callback function.

```
function($scope,..){
    //code goes here.
}
```

where `...` are other dependencies.

---

```
var app = {};
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])

//Login Controller
app.Controller('LoginController', '$scope', '$location', 'User' function($scope, $location, User){
    $scope.initializeScopeVariables();
    $scope.createScopeFunctions();

        $scope.initializeScopeVariables= function () {
                $scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername = null;
        }

        $scope.createScopeFunctions= function () {
            $scope.reset = function () {
                    $scope.$root.filters = {};
                    $scope.resetForm();
            }
            $scope.submit = function () {
                    $scope.submitForm();
            }
            $scope.validate = function () {
                    if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
                            $('#submit-btn').linkbutton('enable');
                    } else {
                            $('#submit-btn').linkbutton('disable');
                    }
            }
            $scope.$root.submitPasswordReminder = function () {
                    if ($scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername) {
                            mask(true);
                            User.sendPasswordReminder($scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername).success(
                                    function (data) {
                                            mask(false);
                                            if (data.status == M2M.Response.ERROR) {
                                                    error(data.statusMessage);
                                            } else {
                                                    info(Locale.get('passwordReminderSent'));
                                                    $scope.clearPasswordReminderForm();
                                            }
                                    }
                            ).error(errorCallback);
                    }
            }

            $scope.$root.clearPasswordReminderForm = function () {
                    $('#forgot-password-window').window('close');
                    $scope.$root.forgotPasswordUsername = null;
            }
            /**
             * Resets login form
             *
             * @param $scope
             */
            $scope.resetForm= function () {
                    $scope.username = '';
                    $scope.password = '';
                    $('input').removeClass('validatebox-invalid');
            },
            /**
             * Submits login form
             *
             * @param $scope
             * @param $location
             * @param User
             */
            $scope.submitForm= function () {
                    if (!($scope.username && $scope.password)) {
                            return;
                    }
                    mask(true);
                    User.authenticate($scope.username, $scope.password).success(
                            function (data) {
                                    if (data.status == M2M.Response.ERROR) {
                                            mask(false);
                                            error(data.statusMessage);
                                    } else {
                                            location.href = 'main.html';
                                    }
                            }
                    ).error(errorCallback);
            }
        }
});
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (13 == event.keyCode) {
                $scope.submit();
                $scope.$apply();
        }
        if (27 == event.keyCode) {
                $scope.reset();
                $scope.$apply();
        }
})
```

i'm hoping it would work, it's just adjusting your own code according to angular 1.5.x. so, let me know if you get any error.

Comment: You are not referring to the OP's explanation that the code is currently working in 1.1.5. This is a migration issue.

Comment: @Boaz i know. it's a different version. no point telling her how to fix one part of her application. i'm giving her a general idea of controllers in Angular 1.5.x. she'll have to make a lot of changes.

Comment: You might explain the difference between the two versions and suggest how to migrate from the old version to the new version, with minimal changes if possible.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is section from an old application written in angular v.1.1.5 which was perfectly working.

Comment: @Margaret if you really have to upgrade it with 1.5.x, then you'll need to change the code. give me a couple of minutes, i'll try to re-write it for you. but it will be untested, so..it might not work right away.